# on asp.net mvc 3 using the razor engine, what's the best practice to pass data between multiple views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

first of all, sorry for my english

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and was trying to develop a simple web application using the Razor Engine

so I have this view called Extract, which accepts an url as input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Begin", "Rss"))
{
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Url) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
<button>Extrair</button>
}
```

when submited, it will send the url to my controller:

```
public ActionResult Begin(ExtractModel m)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var extractedData = ExtractorService.Extract(m.Url);
                if (extractedData != null)
                {
                    TempData["extractedData"] = extractedData;
                    return RedirectToAction("Extracted", extractedData);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

then a new view called Extracted will show all the links extracted from the rss passed:

```
public ActionResult Extracted(ExtractedModel m)
        {
            if (TempData["extractedData"] != null)
            {
                ViewData["extractedData"] = TempData["extractedData"];
                return View(ViewData["extractedData"] as ExtractedModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Extract");
            }
        }
```

-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var data in Model.Data)
    {
<ul>
    <li><a href="@data.Link">@data.Link</a></li>
</ul>
    }
<button>Converter</button>
}
```

**bottom line what I want to ask is: how do I get the ViewData["extractedData"] which I set when loading this View so I can pass it back to the controller and parse all the info inside of it?** because when I click on the button Converter my ViewData is empty and I can't process anything without it =\

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use TempData for passing complex objects between the views. I would also get rid of ViewData.

Then I would rather have the controller action rendering the view fetch whatever information it needs:

```
public class RssController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Extract()
    {
        var model = new ExtractModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Begin(string url)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Extracted", new { url = url });
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

have the corresponding view which allows for entering the url (`~/Views/Rss/Extract.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.ExtractModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Begin", "Rss"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Url) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
    <input type="submit" value="Extrair" />
}
```

and in the other action you are redirecting to:

```
public ActionResult Extracted(string url)
{
    var extractedData = ExtractorService.Extract(url);
    if (extractedData != null)
    {
        return View(extractedData);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Extract");
}
```

Comment: I think I got what you mean, I was passing unnecessary data between the views, right? Now I'm just wondering, since the view "Extracted" gets the url, extracts the rss informationg and send the parsed urls to the client. How can I have this same data sent to another view if the user decides to continue with the extraction?